# Where can I see the usage history of my CharlieCard?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, boston

I am currently traveling in Massachusetts, USA.

Where can I see the usage history of my CharlieCard (issued by the CharlieCard in Boston, Massachusetts, USA)? I.e., I would like to see a log such as:

```
2017-02-14 19:12 - 46 USD  (1 ticket)
2017-02-14 16:57 - 48 USD  (1 ticket)
2017-02-14 16:56 - 50 USD  (recharge)
2017-02-14 10:42 -  0 USD  (1 ticket)
2017-02-14 10:15 -  2 USD  (1 ticket)
```

One of my goals is to ensure I haven't double-tapped the card.

Comment: Have you created an account? If so, is the information available? Otherwise, you might be able to ask a station attendant if they have access to that information.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, so I won't post this as an answer, but I believe there's no way to do this online. The CharlieCard system is an older one and isn't setup with a centralized database that tracks history in this way. You can't even track your balance online, just add more money and passes (which are loaded onto your card when you touch it at a faregate the next day) and report cards lost or stolen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see these details on the mbta website.

- Requested Order > Selected Stored Value
- Actual Card Details > Last Known Stored Value
- Actual Card Details > Last Known Transaction
- Actual Card Details > Last Updated Timestamp

Here is how to see details of your card

1. Go to [MyCharlie Account Center](https://charliecard.mbta.com/CharlieCardWebProgram/pages/showProductIV.jsf)

   - Be careful on this page. The website is antiquated and unforgiving. If you click on any of the links on the left sidebar that navigate to URLs prefixed with `www.mbta` instead of `charliecard` and then click back to the original page, it will redirect you back to the page you clicked on by mistake.
2. Create an account if you don't have one
3. Login
4. If you haven't added a card yet, click `Add / Remove CharlieCards` and follow the instructions

   - If you try to add the card and see the following error `Unfortunately, this CharlieCard isn't valid for usage within the system`, it's possible that the card has expired. The expiration on the bottom right e.g. `Exp 08/29` means it will expire in Aug 2029.
   - The card may have a value on it but may not be internet activated. You can go down to Downtown Crossing and ask to exchange it for one that is... Then you should be able to add it.
   - You can contact the MBTA at 1-888-844-0355.
5. Go back to `MyCharlie Account Center`
6. Click on `Add single purchase of stored value`
7. Select the card from the dropdown
8. Click on `Show Card Details`
9. Celebrate your tenacity

[image: charliecarddetails]

Comment: These steps didn't work for any of my 3 Charlie cards. The last known value and location show up as blank for all 3.

Comment: Charlie cards expire on a fixed date.  They could be expired.

Comment: @Steve I had a similar issue and it's possible that the card is not internet activated. I spoke with the MBTA service center and they said I could replace the card in Downtown Crossing with a card that would work over the internet.

Comment: @gamma_sponge the expiration date `Exp 08/29` at the bottom right of the card means it will expire Aug 2029. While it is possible that @Steve's card is expired, it could also mean his card is not internet activated.